# Oracle 11gR2 11202 issue with kglLockOwnersListAppend-ovf on high volume

Tags: oracle, locking, oracle11g, ora-00600

We just migrate from 9i to 11gR2 11202 and we are experiencing major issue with the KGL_LOCK.

We have something like 1000 dedicated connections to our database.  The frontend is oracle forms.

At some point we are getting this error and then database lock.

ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kglLockOwnersListAppend-ovf], [0xACFF3BE20], [0xA2754D2D0], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For ORA-600 errors I suggest you open a call with Oracle Support.

ORA-600 is Oracle's code for an "internal" error, which may require diagnostics by Oracle Support to fix.

(assuming you can't find anything helpful in google)

Comment: Thank you, We are actually talking with oracle support since a week and they seems to have hard time spotting the issue, so that's why I'm asking over here to see if anybody got this.